# Excel sheet data in Excel dashboard grouping by one column as x axis and sum of other column as y axis

Tags: excel, dashboard

I am trying my hand on the excel dashboards for the first time.
I have some data in one sheet like below:

```
Story  Assignee StoryPoint
XYZ    Amit      3
sdg    Sumit     4
tghgj  Shweta    2
fgjhd  Amit      3
gfhfhj Shweta    2
```

In the second sheet i am trying to depict this data in the chart with my X-Axis has assignees and Y axis has sum of the story points.

Can someone guide me on how can i achieve that?
I just want to have the idea on what all can i implement and the rest i can explore.

Comment: What have you try so far?  Have you try `pivot chart`?

Comment: Nope ..Let me try that

Comment: Thanks @PaichengWu I explored that option and that worked perfectly for me.

Comment: FYI if you have found an answer you can either delete your own post, or post out the solution which may help others who come across a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `Pivot Chart`.

example below could be helpful

https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/pivot-chart.html